# How to get size of storage on Realm Object Server in iOS?

Tags: ios, realm

I have iOS app with Realm MD, so I need to calculate size of storage on Realm Object Server and local Realm Storage, how I can do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You're asking for both iOS and Realm Object Server. While brevity is a good thing, those are diffferent platforms. I would suggest you to ask the Object Server in another question. I think those are two separate matters.

Comment: I've created another question for ROS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232169/size-of-storage-on-realm-object-server

Answer (score 1):

The size of the Realm database on the local storage can be obtained with:

```
// Error and data dictionary
NSError *sizeErr = nil;
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration].fileURL.path
                                                                                error:&sizeErr];

if (sizeErr != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"DB size (in bytes) is: %@", [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize]);
}
```

Comment: ...but if I use syncConfiguration for realm configuration, fileURL = nil

Comment: I'm getting from Realm docs that the `fileURL` property on the `RLMRealmConfiguration` class is (only) mutually exclusive with the `inMemoryIdentifier` property, unrelated to any sync configuration. With the synced realm you should have no issues while getting the `fileURL` property. Can you provide us with your configuration code anyway? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Egor is correct. When a Realm is synchronized, it's stored in a separate location in the app, and the `fileURL` property is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Just like my colleague answered in [the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232169/size-of-storage-on-realm-object-server), there's no public API to get the physical file size of a synchronized Realm at this point.

Because synchronized Realms are tied to user accounts (That could change as users log in and out), they are given unique filenames that cannot be predicted and managed directly by Realm in a special folder in the app's Documents directory. As such, the `fileURL` property in `Configuration` will return nil.

The Realm Mobile Platform is still heavily in development, and we're welcoming all the feedback we can get. If you have a specific use-case in mind for why you need to know the offline file size, please file an issue on the [Realm Mobile Platform GitHub page](https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues).