# Size of storage on Realm Object Server

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have iOS project integrated with RMP, so how I can get size of storage from Realm Object Server?

Comment: Do you mean obtain the size of the storage used for a specific Realm file? The server as a whole? A user?

Comment: I mean obtain the size of the storage used for a specific Realm file

Comment: @teotwaki - Did you consider writing a simple web service that queries the OS for the file size?  As a temporary measure it might provide what you need.

Comment: I believe that comment was for @EgorAfanasenko

Comment: Thanks!...but I can't write web services at all

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to query the server for the size usage of a specific Realm file. This is an API that will (most probably) come at a later date.

As a reminder, the Realm Object Server needs to keep the entirety of the history, in order to allow old joiners to merge and get updated to the latest version.